# Has any etymologist entertained the possibility that "anas" (duck) and "anser" (goose) are related?

Tags: etymology

The word "anser" (goose) is usually derived irregularly from Proto-Indo-European *g<sup>jh</sup>h<sub>2</sub>ens, with an unexplained loss of 'h' at the beginning. I am wondering, has any etymologist considered the possibility that "anser" doesn't actually come from there, but that it is related to "anas" (duck)?

Comment: Where would the *s* in *anser* come from? The *s* in *anas* is the nominative ending; the stem is *anat-*.

Comment: more critically, anser has a long a in the first syllable, where anas has a short one

Comment: (although a suffix beginning with t, and then loss of the medial a could potentially explain both issues, but that requires just as many unexplained irregularities than linking anser to goose does)

Comment: @Tristan A vowel before *-ns-* is always long (and probably nasalized).

Comment: @Cairnarvon ah yep, good point